# Cannot convert int to int*

Tags: c++, char, int

I'm a beginner with C++ and want to make a class named 'Garment' in which I coded:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

class Garments
{
    char GCode[15];
    char GType[15];
    int GSize;
    char GFabric[15];
    float GPrice;

    void Assign() {
        if(strcmp(GFabric,"COTTON")==0) {
            if(strcmp(GType,"TROUSER")==0)
                GPrice=1300;
            else if(strcmp(GType,"SHIRT")==0)
                GPrice=1100;
        } else {
            if(strcmp(GType,"TROUSER")==0)
                GPrice=1300-0.10*1300;
            else if(strcmp(GType,"SHIRT")==0)
                GPrice=1100-0.10*1100;
        }
    }
public:

    Garments() {
        strcpy(GCode,"NOT ALLOWED");
        strcpy(GType,"NOT ALLOWED");
        strcpy(GFabric,"NOT ALLOWED");
        GSize=0;
        GPrice=0;
    }

    void Input() {
        cout<<"Enter Garment Code:";
        cin>>GCode;
        cout<<"\nEnter Garment Type(TROUSER/SHIRT)";
        cin>>GType;
        cout<<"\nEnter Garment Size:";
        gets(GSize);
        cout<<"\nEnter Garment Fabric:";
        gets(GFabric);
        Assign();
    }

    void Display() {
        cout<<"Garment Code:"<<GCode;
        cout<<"\nGarment Type:"<<GType;
        cout<<"\nGarment Size:"<<GSize;
        cout<<"\nGarment Fabric:"<GFabric;
        cout<<"\nGarment Price:"<<GPrice;
    }
};

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    Garments G;
    G.Input();
    G.Display();
    getch();
}
```

Is the upper code correct? While compiling in Turbo C++, I have two errors:

1. Cannot convert `int` to `char*`.
2. Type mismatch in parameter `__s`in call to `gets(char*)`.

Both the errors are in line `gets(GSize);`
How to correct the error?

Comment: use a modern compiler and use `std::string` for strings. There is literally no value in trying to learn C++ as it was 25 years ago

Comment: Please format your code it hurts my [eyes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juFZh92MUOY)

Comment: `gcc` adds line numbers to the errors: `40:11: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'char*'`, `49:34: warning: value computed is not used`, and `52:11: error: '::main' must return 'int'`.

Comment: Why the sudden switch from `cin>>` to `gets`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do a search on the functions that don't work for you and read about them and understand them. In this case: [gets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/)

Which is short for "get string". An int is an int. Not a string!

Comment: `Which is short for "get string"`: Not really, it's more like longwinded `BUG` (subcategory UB, subcategory buffer overflow, subcategory stack-overflow).